# About bootstrap grid, the element shows in an column but not a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7pZp.png)
Here is my code, I wanna the elements stand in a row from left to right, but, it turns out to be in a column from top to the end...my friend said I use the for.each..circle in a wrong way but I don't know where is my fault...

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <!-- <%= image_tag product.image.thumb %> -->
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <!-- <div style="border:1px solid #eee;padding:2px;float:left;margin-right:10px"><%= image_tag product.image.thumb %></div> -->
   <!-- <img src="product.image.thumb"/> -->
   <%= image_tag product.image.thumb %>
      <div class="caption">
        <h5>《<%=link_to(product.title, product_path(product))%>》 </h5>
         <!-- <p><%= product.description %></p> -->
         <table class="table table-boldered">
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <td>售价</td>
               <td>库存</td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td><%= product.price %></td>
               <td><%= product.quantity %></td>
           </tr>
         </table>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Collect</a></p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you are creating a single column. Try `<% @products.each do |product| %>` before `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">`

Answer (score 0):

If you want align three image in a row, then Bootstrap solution will be like this:

```
<div class="row">

       <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>
                    Project 2
                </p>
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>
                    Project 2
                </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>
                    Project 2
                </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: thankyou, but i am using this in a circular ,it seems to be a better solution like....in one command,your method will do well for common situation,but it may not fit...have some other ideas?